# Google Chrome not opening when i use vpn

Tags: google-chrome, vpn

i am using obuntu 22.04, I have been facing this problem for a few days now, when I connect to the vpn (Qv2ray), Google Chrome cannot open a page and it shows this error:
this site can’t be reached: err_timed_out

Thank you for your time and help.

Kind regards.